# Waiting for AJAX with Capybara + Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I've seen various implementations of the `wait_for_ajax` method that makes Capybara wait until all AJAX requests are completed before moving forward.

I've just switched to using Poltergeist as my JavaScript driver and I'm having trouble getting it to wait for the AJAX to complete on a test (see below)

Below is the implementation that was previously working with Selenium - the only thing I modified was the evaluation script -

- Previous: `page.evaluate_script("jQuery.active")`
- Updated: `page.evaluate_script("$.active").to_i`

If I insert a `sleep` statement it passes because it has enough time to finish the AJAX call, so I definitely know that's the issue.

Is there any error in this approach?

Thanks!

```
it "user can log in", js: true do
  visit root_path
  click_tab("log-in")

  # Fill in form
  fill_in "user[email]", with: "al-horford@hawks.com"
  fill_in "user[password]", with: "sl4mdunkz"

  # Click submit and wait for AJAX
  within("#log-in") { click_button("Log In")) }
  wait_for_ajax

  # Expectations
  expect(current_path).to eq(home_index_path)
end

def wait_for_ajax
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
  end
end

def finished_all_ajax_requests?
  request_count = page.evaluate_script("$.active").to_i
  request_count && request_count.zero?
rescue Timeout::Error
end
```

Comment: Just use the have_current_path matcher - `expect(page).to have_current_path(home_index_path)` and capybara will wait for the path to change. There are really very few instances where wait_for_ajax should be needed, and using Timeout with poltergeist can cause all sorts of issues with the message parsing stack due to its raising of errors in threads not expecting them

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll use that matcher. However, regardless of how it should or should not be used, is there a way to still address the original question and get that implementation working? Thanks!

Comment: It should "work" as written, assuming you're not using `noconflict` and you have no JS errors preventing things from running.

Comment: We use `page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').to_i > 0` in our poltergeist version of `wait_for_ajax` and it works for us.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, there are some situations wait_for_ajax will not wait for.

In our app, we have a 'to cart'-button that triggers Ajax. It then waits for a callback event before it loads the next page. This is not picked up by wait_for_ajax.

What fixed it, and what is generally a better approach than waiting a given amount of time with sleep(), is to verify that you're on the next page using one of Capybara's waiting finders.

Simply replace `expect(current_path).to eq(home_index_path)`

with something like `expect(page).to have_content("content_home_page_should_have")`

That should work.

Comment: Also it can be written in more natural for Capybara way like `expect(page).to have_current_path(home_index_path)`

Comment: I know this is old however I just stumbled across the same issue and the only way I can get it to work is with sleep(3) or similar. My standard thoughtbot wait_for_ajax method and the one you mentioned here don't work whether alone or in combination. Any ideas?